Two of the three furthest nodes in a tree must lie on the diameter
I'm working on finding a set of three nodes (a, b, c) that maximize number of unique edges that on the paths between a, b, and c - {P(a,b) U (P(b,c) U P(a,c)} where P(x,y) is a path (edges) between x and y (formal definition below).
formal definition, P - path, E - edges
I've developed an algorithm to achieve this, but I'm struggling with proving correctness. I need to show that two of these three nodes must lie on the tree diameter. However, I'm stuck at this point and can't seem to move forward.
My algorithm:

Find Diameter (a, b)
Remove the edges that lie on the diameter, which splits the tree into disjoint subtrees
Using DFS from each Node on the diameter as root find deepest Node. (that node is c)
Return a, b, c


What is tree's diameter?

Sorry - diameter of a tree - Longest path between any two nodes

IMHO, this question rather belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

What are you trying to maximize? What is the subtree in step 3? We don't have enough detail on either the task or the algorithm to say whether this is correct. (It's probably not, though - if you don't know how to prove an algorithm you came up with is correct, you don't have a good reason to believe it is correct.)

Hi. I hope that edit clarified everything.

The edit helps, but it's still not clear what you're trying to maximize.

Are you trying to find 3 nodes with the greatest possible sum of pairwise distances between them?

There is a link to the formal definition of the set. I need to maximize the number of unique edges that on the paths between a, b, and c - {P(a,b) U (P(b,c) U P(a,c)} where P(x,y) is a path (edges) between x and y

I have asked my professor about correctness of the algorithm and it should work.

It is easy to prove by reductio ad absurdum. Suppose neither pair (a,b), (b,c), (c,a) lies on the diameter. Call the subtree that contains all three vertices S. It has a vertex r such that (a,r), (b,r) and (c,r) have no edges in common. Then we can find a diameter (d,e) and build a bigger vertex set.
Consider several cases: (1) (d,e) is disjoint from S; (2) (d,e) has one vertex in common with S and it is r; (3) (d,e) has one or more vertices in common with S and they all lie on (a,r); (4) (d,e) has one or more vertices in common with S and they all lie on (a,r) and (b,r). (Other cases are symmetrical). In each case it is easy to see that there is a triple that contains d and e whose edge set is bigger than that of (a,b,c).

I see that. Thanks
